# Error testing step function locally: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-sam

I am trying to test a step function locally. I have defined my stateMachine.json and added my credentials (**aws_access_key_id** and **aws_secret_access_key**) with `aws configure` .

I am following this steps to run the state machine: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-lambda.html. But when I start the execution I get this error:

`2021-08-08 05:37:56.464: arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:execution:StateMachine:firstTest : {"Type":"LambdaFunctionFailed","PreviousEventId":4,"LambdaFunctionFailedEventDetails":{"Error":"Lambda.AWSLambdaException","Cause":"The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 66622740-bcbc-4397-8c97-75454dca550d; Proxy: null)"}}`

Which can be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set environmental variable `LAMBDA_ENDPOINT` as `host.docker.internal`.

---

At [Step 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-lambda.html#start-local-lambda), you run this command:

```
sam local start-lambda
```

The output is like:

```
...
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:3001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Remember `3001`, this will be used below.

Then, refer to [Step Functions Local configuration options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-config-options.html).
It says, `aws-stepfunctions-local-credentials.txt` contains credentials.

Include `LAMBDA_ENDPOINT=http://host.docker.internal:3001`.

Example of credential file:

```
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID= ...
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION= ...
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= ...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= ...
LAMBDA_ENDPOINT=http://host.docker.internal:3001
```